# How to allow certain groups only to create and edit but not delete (drop) tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I'm building an app using AWS RDS PostgreSQL.

I need to allow one group to use `CREATE, INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` statements, but at the same time not allow them to use `DROP TABLE` or `DROP DATABASE`.

Is there a way to do this on the database layer, as I would prefer not to do it on server-side layer? Thank you.

Comment: This is better suited at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one privileged user that can do all these things – let's call it `creator` – and a normal user `luser` that is used to log into the database.

`creator` then defines PL/pgSQL functions with `SECURITY DEFINER` that perform the required `CREATE` statements (probably using dynamic SQL with an `EXECUTE` statement).

Then `creator` runs

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION ... FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION ... TO luser;
```

so that `luser` can execute the functions.

`INSERT` and `UPDATE` privileges are granted to `luser` inside the functions.

Documentation links:

- Language [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) to write functions in PostgreSQL
- [Executing dynamic statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in PL/pgSQL
- [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) SQL sommand
- [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-priv.html) in PostgreSQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing it just with grants and revokes, but that wasn't working because (I think) there isn't an option to explicitly revoke "drop" commands. Is there some link I can read further about this?

Comment: I have added links to the documentation.